# How to populate the default to dropdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

Good day

My code below populate the lists of warehouses to a dropdown, which is what i want but i also want do make the warehouse with `isMainWarehouse = true` a default selected when populating the warehouses (note that there is only one main warehouse)

```
function PopulateWarehouses() {

var warehouseDropDown = document.getElementById('SelectWarehouse');
var warehouseFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

_warehouseRepository.getWarehouses().done(function (data) {
    for (var element in data.items) {
        if (data.items.hasOwnProperty(element)) {

            var recievedData = data.items[element];
            var id = recievedData.id;
            var name = recievedData.warehouseName;
            var main = recievedData.isMainWarehouse;
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = name;
            opt.value = id;
            warehouseFragment.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
    warehouseDropDown.appendChild(warehouseFragment);
    $('#SelectWarehouse').selectpicker('refresh');

});}
```

here is my dropdown

```
 <select id="SelectWarehouse" name="SelectWarehouse" class="selectpicker show-tick  form-control" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

This method just get the list of all the warehouses

```
 // GET: get list of all warehouses
    public async Task<ListResultOutput<WarehouseListDto>> GetWarehouses()
   {
        var warehouses = await _warehouseRepository.GetAllListAsync();


        ListResultOutput<WarehouseListDto> dto = new ListResultOutput<WarehouseListDto>(
                 warehouses
                .OrderBy(t => t.WarehouseName)
                .ToList()
                .MapTo<List<WarehouseListDto>>()
            );
        return dto;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select the main one, you just need to set the selected property of the option for the main warehouse

```
function PopulateWarehouses() {

var warehouseDropDown = document.getElementById('SelectWarehouse');
var warehouseFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

_warehouseRepository.getWarehouses().done(function (data) {
    for (var element in data.items) {
        if (data.items.hasOwnProperty(element)) {

            var recievedData = data.items[element];
            var id = recievedData.id;
            var name = recievedData.warehouseName;
            var main = recievedData.isMainWarehouse;
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = name;
            if(main){
                opt.selected = 'selected';
            }
            opt.value = id;
            warehouseFragment.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
    warehouseDropDown.appendChild(warehouseFragment);
    $('#SelectWarehouse').selectpicker('refresh');

});}
```